# Change td background color with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have spent a few hours on this trying various things but have failed thus far.

I am trying to set the background color of a td (.myTD) to a variable color.

I know the DOM has been loaded already and i have confirmed all class names are correct etc..

Code:

```js
var appInfo = {"ads":[{"bgColor":"#FFF"}]};

$(".myTD").css('background-color', appInfo.ads[0].bgColor + ' !important');
console.log("variable = " + appInfo.ads[0].bgColor);
console.log($(".myTD").css('background-color'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="myTD">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

no errors in console. just the logs from the code.

Comment: What happens if you change your code to: `$(".myTD").css('background-color', '#FFF !important');`  and then `$(".myTD").css('background-color', '#F00 !important');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066

jQuery not supported `!important` in `.css()`
You can use this

```
$(".myTD").css('cssText', 
   'background-color:'+ appInfo.ads[0].bgColor + ' !important');
```

```js
var appInfo = {"ads":[{"bgColor":"#FFF"}]};


var color = 

$(".myTD").css('cssText',
   'background-color:'+ appInfo.ads[0].bgColor + ' !important');
console.log("variable = " + appInfo.ads[0].bgColor);
console.log($(".myTD").css('background-color'));
```

```css
td{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="myTD">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```